# If N is a normal subgroup of a group G, then prove that G/N is a group with respect to multiplication of cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I can prove that G/N follows closure property, associative property, has identity and inverse with respect to multiplication of cosets. But after this, what should I do to prove that G/N is a group with respect to multiplication of cosets?

Comment: Nothing...or perhaps just "voilá, there is the proof!"! After proving those four properties with a non-empty set and a binary operation on it you are done.

Comment: Looks like you already dealt with all group axioms.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you for answering. Just one more thing, Can any body do the existence of identity property for the above question. I have a little doubt in that part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping✌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\;1\cdot N=N\;$ be an element in $\;G/N\;$ , with $\;1\;$ the unit in the group $\;G\;$ , then for any $\;g\in G\;$ we get

$$(gN)(1N):=(g\cdot 1)N=gN\implies N\;\text{ is the unit in the group}\;\;G/N$$